# FirebaseDatabase - removeAllObservers() - What does it actually remove?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

Does the `removeAllObservers()` removes all observers **only** for `DatabaseReference` instance it's called on, or any reference at specified path?

For example:

```
MainController.swift

let ref = Database.(...).child("foo/bar").observe(.value, with: handler)



ItemController.swift

public var ref2: DatabaseReference?

public func someMethod() {
    self.ref2 = Database.(...).child("foo/bar").observe(.value, with: handler2)
}

override func viewDidDisappear() {
    self.ref2?.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Will `ref` from **MainController** still observe **foo/bar** path or this observer will be removed as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write):

> If multiple listeners have been added to a database reference, each
>   listener is called when an event is raised. In order to stop syncing
>   data at that location, you must remove all observers at a location by
>   calling the removeAllObservers method.
>
> Calling removeObserverWithHandle or removeAllObservers on a listener
>   does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child nodes;
>   you must also keep track of those references or handles to remove
>   them.

So in other words you need to remove them all, they will no automatically be removed and `ref` from **MainController** will still observe.

Comment: Yep, but keep in mind, that I'm observing the exact same paths with two different references. That's the point. The thing is: I'm observing **foo/bar** in MainController, but as I navigate through app, I get to ItemController which observe the **foo/bar** as well, but removesAllObservers on **viewDidDisappear**. Will the **foo/bar** observer from MainController still listen for changes?

Comment: @jpawlowski When you remove the observer it does not listen anymore. Make sure you removing the observer with correct form and correct path.

Comment: @jpawlowski, it will still listen. You need to use `removeAllObservers` for all paths.

Comment: You mean 'for all references'? I'm observing the same path in two separate places, so I've got two DatabaseReference instances observing the same **foo/bar** path.

Comment: @jpawlowski, yes you need to remove the observer for each class. It will not be removed from both places.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs `ref2` will still observe.

There is no way to remove all observers for *all* paths.